# Using textacular gem, how do I match one word in a large body of text?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, full-text-search

I have a rails (4.2.3) blog app with the textacular gem with a `Post` model having `title:string` and `body:text`.

I create a post:

```
> my_post = Post.create! title: 'my post', body: 'this post is about physics and ...'
```

Now, I want the search for 'physics' to match the body, but it doesn't. If I try:

```
> Post.basic_search('physics').first #=> nil
```

If I change the body to be shorter, it works:

```
> my_post.body = "about physics"
> my_post.save!
> Post.basic_search('physics').first #=> <my_post>
```

I have also tried fuzzy_search instead of basic search, but it gives the same result.

How do I use textacular to search for existence of words in long text fields?

Answer (score 1):

README on Github says `Model.basic_search` will search only `string` columns of the model:

```
Game.basic_search('Sonic') # will search through the model's :string columns
Game.basic_search(title: 'Mario', system: 'Nintendo')
```

And for `fuzzy searches` README says:

> Note that fuzzy searches are subject to a similarity threshold imposed by the pg_trgm module. The default is 0.3, meaning that at least 30% of the total string must match your search content.

You can set the  similarity threshold to a very small value on large text fields.

Reference: [Github](https://github.com/textacular/textacular)

Comment: basic_search seems to work with all stringish fields (text included). Setting the fuzzy_search threshold is very ambiguous, because I do not know what the field lengths will be, so any guess at a lower threshold is just a guess. If I set the threshold too low, then even completely unrelated records land up matching.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using a gin index like so, which then gives me the matches I want (with basic_search:

```
# in a migration
execute "create index on posts using gin(to_tsvector('english', body));"

# console query
> my_post = Post.create! title: 'my post', body: 'this post is about physics and ...'
> Post.basic_search('physics').first #=> <my_post>
```